# Call to undefined method App\Models\User::attachRole()

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing Laratrust roles and permissions in Laravel 10. I am getting this error when I run UserSeeder to create an admin.I followed all the steps, step by step, in installing Laratrust. But I don't know where the problem is or what mistake I committed during the installation of Laratrust.

This is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Laratrust\Contracts\LaratrustUser;
use Laratrust\Traits\HasRolesAndPermissions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements LaratrustUser
{
    use HasRolesAndPermissions;
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

This is UserSeeder

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;

class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $admin = new User() ;
        $admin->name = "admin";  
        $admin->email = "admin@gmail.com";
        $admin->password=encrypt('123456');
        $admin->save();
        $admin->attachRole('admin');
    }
}
```

I run the Laratrust seeder first and then UserSeeder separately, but I still get the error.

Comment: It's `addRole()`, not `attachRole()`

Comment: Thanks. I am following an old tutorial in which it is used as attachRole but it's wrong it's "addRole". Thanks for the help.

Comment: In case you couldn't find Laratrust's documentation: https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/8.x/

Answer (score 0):

The method name is `addRole()`, not `attachRole()`.

You can use the `addRole()` method on your `User` model to attach a specific role as follows:

Add a role by its name:

```
$admin->addRole("admin");
```

Add a role by its ID:

```
$admin->addRole(1); // assuming the admin role id is 1
```

Add a role by assigning the respective `\Laratrust\Models\Role` model:

```
$role = \Laratrust\Models\Role::find(1); // assuming the admin role id is 1
$admin->addRole($role);
```

Please notice that it's always recommended that you always go with the first option since it's the most readable.

You can find more information here: https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/8.x/usage/roles-and-permissions.html#assignment-2